# Can we use chrome extensions in selenium pythonanywhere?

Tags: python, selenium, pythonanywhere

I am working on a flask app which is hosted on pythonanywhere, and I want to use chrome extensions with my chrome driver.But, it looks like pythonanywhere does not have any support for chrome extensions.
(I tried adding extensions both using crx and zip)

Any form of help will be considered HUGE!

I tried using

```
chrome_options.add_extension('Comic-Sans-Everything.zip')
```

and also running it in headless mode:

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless=chrome")
```

I also tried pyvirtualdisplay but in vain. awaiting help from the community!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the extension file that you're trying to use is actually there and that you are using the correct path to it: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/NoSuchFileOrDirectory/